# Integration proof question

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $R \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be a rectangle.

Assume that $f: R \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is integrable on $R$.

Let $P$ be a partition of $R$.

Define the characteristic function to be $J_{R_j}1(x)= 1$ if $x \in R_j$ and $0$ otherwise.

**Want to show**: Define a function $g$ such that $g$ is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{J} a_jJ_{R_j}1(x)$ where $a_j \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following two properties hold:

1. $g(x) \leq f(x) \forall x\in R$
2. $\int\int_R gdA=L(P,f)$ where $L(P,f)$ represents the lower sum.

**My problem:** How should I be defining $g$? Since the characteristic function is just a constant $1$ or $0$ I am really just CHOOSING the scalars, i.e. $a_j$... but not sure.

In case it might not be clear $a_jJ_{R_j}1(x)= a_j$ if $x\in R_j$ and $0$ otherwise.

I hope I am not missing any other hypothesis if it is the case I will update immediately. Thanks.

Comment: What's the deal with $T$?  It never showed up again.

Comment: Sorry about that that needs to be removed.

Comment: Any help please? :(